# Vector2.Transform(Vector2, Matrix) returns {X:n. def. Y:n. def.}

Tags: matrix, monogame

I'm trying to convert a Vector2 screen position to a world position. I've found this nice method in another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995094/how-to-calculate-screen-to-world-position-in-2d-game):

```
public Vector2 ScreenToWorld(Vector2 onScreen)
{
    var matrix = Matrix.Invert(World.Camera.CurrentTransformation);
    return Vector2.Transform(onScreen, matrix);
}
```

But when I use this with the Matrix of my camera it only returns this:

```
{X:n. def. Y:n. def.}    // Output of Vector2.ToString()
```

My Matrix is build like this:

```
m_transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-m_position.X, -m_position.Y, 0f)) *
    Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(m_zoom, m_zoom, 0)) *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(m_viewport.Width / 2f, m_viewport.Height / 2f, 0));
```

When I try to compare the result with other Vector2 positions it allways return true. For Example, I have a clickable object, and even if I click outside of the object it returns that it is being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Not every matrix can be inverted.

Inverting a matrix is essentially trying to figure out where a point started out before being multiplied with the matrix. This can only work if no two points are transformed to the same location when multiplied whit the matrix.

In this case, you essentially multiply the z coordinate by 0. So the points (0|0|0) and (0|0|1) get mapped to the same position. That means that your matrix cannot be inverted. If you change that line, you will probably be able to create a matrix that can be inverted.

You might also consider to use one of Monogame's built-in camera and projection matrix functions instead, like `CreateLookAt()`, `CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView()` and `CreateOrthographic()`.